# Elapsed time according to status change

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working with a chatbot dataset and having trouble creating a column with the elapsed time of two dates in the same column. I need to calculate this time difference based on a status change  - when it was previously IN and then become OUT its necessary to calculate the elapsed time from the previous row.

| Contact_ID | In_out | Date | Response Time (secs) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1H2H000005QCNNUA4 | IN | 10/10/2022 14:00:00 |  |
| a1H2H000005QCNNUA4 | IN | 10/10/2022 14:00:01 |  |
| a1H2H000005QCNNUA4 | OUT | 10/10/2022 14:02:01 | 120 |
| l3H2H000005QCNNUH3 | IN | 10/10/2022 18:10:00 |  |
| l3H2H000005QCNNUH3 | IN | 10/10/2022 18:10:01 |  |
| l3H2H000005QCNNUH3 | IN | 10/10/2022 18:10:02 |  |
| l3H2H000005QCNNUH3 | OUT | 10/10/2022 18:15:02 | 300 |

I've tried to summarize the contact_id in a created table but it did not workout since a contact_id can have multiple IN and OUT status changes.I was expecting to get a datediff between the first OUT row and the previous IN row to each contact_id.

Any idea on how to procceed ?

Answer (score 0):

You can you M language to achieve your goal.

Let's say that your Dataset is called `Source`.

First step is to Group by `Contact_ID` AND `In_out`:

```
 #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Source", {"Contact_ID", "In_out"}, {{"Date", each List.Min([Date]), type nullable datetime}})
```

Second Step is to Group by `Contact_ID` and get `Date_IN` and `Date_OUT`:

```
#"Grouped Rows1" = Table.Group(#"Grouped Rows", {"Contact_ID"}, {{"Date_IN", each List.Min([Date]), type nullable datetime}, {"Date_OUT", each List.Max([Date]), type nullable datetime}})
```

And finally calculate Elapsed time:

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows1", "Elapsed Time", each Duration.TotalSeconds([Date_OUT] - [Date_IN]))
```